# CSS calc function does not center

Tags: html, css, scss-mixins

I need to use the calc function for width but it doesn't divide distance around.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-card">
    <div class="container-holder"></div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.container-card {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 500px;
    .container-holder {
        background-color: gold;
        width: calc(100% - 14px);
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/fze3L0w8/

In other words: I need 14px distance from left and right in every width.

Comment: you need to center the `.container-holder` ? Be more specific.

Comment: You need to use margin or display flex property to align items inside a div https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `margin:auto;` for adding space from both side. And you need to set it `100% - 28px`

```css
.container-card {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 500px;
   
  }
   .container-holder {
      background-color: gold;
      width: calc(100% - 28px);
      height: 300px;
      margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-card">
    <div class="container-holder">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: margin works alone so why should use calc?

Comment: #heliya rb because we are only only need 28px from the total width. So, we are calc using.

Comment: if we use margin 14px for left and right always set 28px from width. it isn't true?

Comment: #heliya rb yes it is true.If you set margin 14px without define width it will take equal space from both side.

Comment: #heliya rb In this case browser will adjust with to auto when you will not set with attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Just set a margin of 14px, and you will no longer need to set the `width` property:

```
.container-card {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 500px;
    .container-holder {
      background-color: gold;
      margin: 14px;
      height: 300px;
    }
}
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1kv79e5/).

Comment: so when I should use calc?

Comment: Sparingly, as it comes with a performance impact. This case is pretty simple to solve without `calc()`: a `div` is a block level element; it already has a default width of 100%, and you can apply margins to it. No need for any calculations.

Answer (score 2):

this is the solution:

```
background-color: gold;
width: calc(100% - 28px);
height: 300px;
margin: auto;
```

you need margin from left o rright also

Answer (score 1):

you either set it `100% - 28px` to reduce width by `14px` **right** and **left** and set `margin: auto;` to center the div

```
.container-card {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 500px;
    .container-holder {
      background-color: gold;
      width: calc(100% - 28px);
      margin: auto;
      height: 300px;
    }
  }
```

or only set `margin:0px 14px;` and no need to set width it will take parent width - margin

```
  .container-card {
        background-color: grey;
        height: 500px;
        .container-holder {
          background-color: gold;
          margin: 0px 14px;
          height: 300px;
        }
      }
```

Comment: margin works alone so why should use calc?

Comment: @heliyarb check updated solution

Answer (score 0):

More elegant solution is that -

```
.container-card {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 500px;
    .container-holder {
      background-color: gold;
      width: calc(100% - 28px);
      height: 300px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  }
```

Calc function will get 28px and to center an element inside another one. use `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Just center the container instead of this hard coded brittle approach with something like flex, then you can use whatever margin you want without it breaking.

```css
.container-card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 500px;
}
.container-holder {
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 0 14px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container-card">
    <div class="container-holder">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747337/flex-cant-use-two-justify-for-one-div. I need help

Answer (score 0):

More elegant solution could be this
`

```
.container-card {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 500px;
    .container-holder {
      background-color: gold;
      margin-left: 14px;
      margin-right:14px;
      height: 300px;
    }
  }
```

`