# flex can't use two justify for one div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need a card list layout for this I use flex. in large device everything is ok but when **device becomes small** and two cards can't be next to each other and **go to the next line**, my content **it's not center**

in other words, I need to **center** my content in all device size and when two cards come together should be **space-between and center**

```css
.container-card {
  background-color: grey;
  direction: rtl;
}

.container-holder {
  background-color: gold;
  width: calc(100% - 28px);
  max-width: 1004px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.request-box {
  width: 481px;
  height: 417px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #adadad;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin: 15px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-card">
  <div class="container-holder">
    <div class="request-box"></div>
    <div class="request-box"></div>
    <div class="request-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Please check the example above in full-page and change the responsive size**

Comment: I don't see any media query.

Comment: I want to handle with flex

Comment: Flexbox cannot do that. That's why we have media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS grid for this:

```css
.container-card {
  background-color: grey;
  direction: rtl;
}

.container-holder {
  background-color: gold;
  width: calc(100% - 28px);
  max-width: 1004px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(481px, 1fr));
  place-items: center;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
}

.request-box {
  width: 481px;
  height: 417px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #adadad;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-card">
  <div class="container-holder">
    <div class="request-box"></div>
    <div class="request-box"></div>
    <div class="request-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: all over my project is by flex

Comment: @heliyarb *all over my project is by flex* --> there is nothing wrong to combine flexbox with CSS grid or any other technique. Flexbox alone cannot do everything

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is helpful for you all in center align and i`m not use any mediaquery same code work on small screens .

```css
.container-card {
            background-color: grey;
        }
        
        .container-holder {
            background-color: #ffd700;
            width: calc(100% - 28px);
            max-width: 1004px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .request-box {
            width: 481px;
            height: 417px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            border: solid 1px #adadad;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            margin-top: 15px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            margin: 15px 2px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-card">
    <div class="container-holder">
        <div class="request-box"></div>
        <div class="request-box"></div>
        <div class="request-box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's ok.is there a solution that the last item starts from right too???

Comment: remove this property on this class.

.container-card {
    background-color: #808080;
    /* direction: rtl; */
}

Comment: remove these properties but it's not related . could you please update your snippet

Answer (score 0):

to set the cards netx to each other in small devices you can use this media query:

```
@media(max-width: 400px){
    .container-holder {
       justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .request-box {
       width: 45%;
    }
}
```

test it . it works nicely!

Comment: That's not what I want. I want to handle by flex

Comment: also, your code doesn't work. please take it in a snippet

Comment: my request-box should have certain and fix width